# Simple WinAPI app has an additional console window

Tags: c++, winapi

I've copy-pasted following skeleton of a simple C++ WinAPI application. It works, but creates an additional console window along with GUI one. How to get rid of it? I am using GCC from MinGW.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static char sClassName[]  = "MyClass";
static HINSTANCE zhInstance = NULL;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
        WNDCLASSEX WndClass;
        HWND hwnd;
        MSG Msg;

        zhInstance = hInstance;

        WndClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        WndClass.style         = NULL;
        WndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        WndClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        WndClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        WndClass.hInstance     = zhInstance;
        WndClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        WndClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        WndClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        WndClass.lpszClassName = sClassName;
        WndClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

        if(!RegisterClassEx(&WndClass)) {
                MessageBox(0, "Error Registering Class!", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
                return 0;
        }

        hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, sClassName, "db Tutorial", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    320, 240, NULL, NULL, zhInstance, NULL);

        if(hwnd == NULL) {
                MessageBox(0, "Error Creating Window!", "Error!", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);
                return 0;
        }

        ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);

        while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
                TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }

        return Msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        switch(Message) {
                case WM_CLOSE:
                        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                        break;
                case WM_DESTROY:
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        break;
                default:
                        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really?   Maybe you are just seeing the compiler shell.

Comment: @M M: That question's title is unclear. I would conclude that the g++ itself causes the window to appear, but not the compiled .exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `-mwindows` option to compile a GUI application. The default, `-mconsole`, creates a console application.

The default heuristic used by the MS linker is: if your program has a `main` function it is  a console program but if it has a `WinMain` function it is a GUI one. But that is not used by the GNU tools. They create a console program by default.

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick. Could I control this behaviour from inside of .cpp text?

Comment: @Paul: I don't think so. AFAIK you cannot pass compiler options to GCC from the source.